# Google Maps API map.fitBounds(markerBounds) throws too much recursion error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, recursion

Hello I have a problem with the Google Maps API. I get the "too much recursion" error.

When I try to add marker to the bound I get the error. I use API v3.

I have search last 6 hours for the Problem :/

Here is my Code:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.controller('MapController', function($scope, $ionicLoading, $http) {


    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {

        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 16,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var markerBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

     $http.get('files/events.json')
       .success(function(res){
            angular.forEach(res.markers, function(value, key) {
                var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(value.laenge, value.breite),
                    map: map,
                    title: value.title
                    });
            markerBounds.extend(marker1.position);
            });       

        });

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
          var testposition = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude);
          var myLocation = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: testposition,
                map: map,
                title: "My Location"
            });
            markerBounds.extend(myLocation.position);

         map.setCenter(testposition);
        map.setZoom(map.fitBounds(markerBounds))
        });

        $scope.map = map;
    });

})
```

Comment: Its mostly because you are looping `markerBounds.extend` in `.forEach` loop. This error is mostly an outcome of a creation of infinite loop that is draining memory. So I suggest you perform bound extend outside of `.forEach`.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19162118/google-maps-using-map-fitbounds-bounds?answertab=votes#tab-top